# Do I have kernel support for fbtft?

Tags: kernel-modules, arm, nano

When I trying this command `modinfo fbtft` I get this result:

```
modinfo: ERROR: Module fbtft not found.
```

But when I do checking, I have `fbtft` file in this location :

```
/lib/modules/3.18.1+/kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/fbtft
```

Do I have kernel support for fbtft or not? if not, how to add it?

My system is an arm-based computer(nanopi-m1) with Allwinner H3 sun8iw7p1 SoC and Debian Jessie OS.

This is the result of `uname -r` :

```
3.4.39-h3
```

Comment: Please add the kernel version running on your board. `uname -r`. Did you copy that module on your own?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean, but I have 2 folders in this path: /lib/modules/3.18.1+/  And /lib/modules/3.4.39-h3/. Maybe I did download one of them in one of those many steps I tried to make my LCD working by the tutorials! I am nebie in linux and don't know much about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/lib/modules/3.18.1+/kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/fbtft` is a directory. `modinfo fbtft` or `modprobe fbtft` looks for a file called `fbtft.ko`, which should be in that directory.

The `fbtft` driver can either be compiled as a module or linked into the main kernel binary. If it's in the main kernel binary then there won't be a file under `/lib/modules`. But at runtime there will be a directory in [sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs), `/sys/module/fbtft`, containing various information about the driver.

Note that the driver you should be loading is actually `fbtft_device`. See the [wiki](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki) for more information.

If the fbtft modules are not included in the kernel you're using, then you'll need to recompile them. But 3.4 is a pretty old kernel; the tbtft drivers were added in 4.0. So you should look for a more recent kernel. Debian jessie, the latest stable release, shipped with 3.16; that's almost recent enough but not quite. There are more recent kernels in the [backports](https://backports.debian.org/).